# ImplicitEquations plotting in Julia

Tags: plot, julia

I'm using ImplicitEquations, Plots in Julia to plot an inequality with 2 variables. I can't see the plot because the space for plotting is in the range [-5,5]. How can I scale it to include a wider range?

This is the code I'm using:

```
f(x,y) = 100 - x * y 
g(x,y) = -25x - 4y + 200 
plot((f <= 0) & (g <= 0))
```

Comment: Pass in xlim, ylim as tuples: `plot((f ≦ 0) & (g ≦ 0), (-100, 100), (-100, 100))`. (This should be changed to use the `xlims=` and `ylims=` conventions in plots though.) Also note, the `<=` is now `\leqq[tab]` (or will be when the package gets tagged). This change is to avoid type piracy.

Answer (score 2):

Use `xlims`

```
plot((f <= 0) & (g <= 0),xlims=(-10,10))
```

Note that this is implemented via a plot recipe. Like anything else implemented by plot recipes, all of these attributes are available:

https://juliaplots.github.io/attributes/

To know which backend supports which attributes, see:

https://juliaplots.github.io/supported/